# Reference resource in top directory (not package) in Java JAR/Eclipse

Tags: java, jar, reference, path

I'm trying to access some resources  located in the top directory of my (Java) project (/resources/imgname.jpg) from a class 'GUI' located in a package 'gui'.

Originally I used the following code:

```
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("./resources/imgname.jpg");
Image img = image.getImage();
```

This works fine in Eclipse, but doesn't display the image when it's in a runnable JAR. So after some searching it seems you need:

```
InputStream resource = GUI.class.getResourceAsStream("./resources/imgname.jpg");
try {
    Image image = ImageIO.read(resource);
} catch (IOException e) {//trycatch needed because of read method}
```

Now this doesn't work in either Eclipse or JAR.
I've tried changing reference and location, but the only way I can get the image to display is by placing it in the 'gui' package folder. So is there any way I can reference it in the top folder of the project instead (so I don't have to move the resources to 'gui')?

Thx,

Magic

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
InputStream resource = GUI.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resources/imgname.jpg");
```

It works for me.

Comment: This still doesn't work for me. The JAR doesn't run, Eclipse gives an exception because the resource I try to pass to ImageIO is still 'null'. Do I have to do something special to the classpath? I've already tried adding the 'resources' folder to the source in Eclipse's build path configuration but it's still giving the same error..

Comment: Ok it's working now. After explicitly adding 'resources' to the build path I just had to use "/imgname.jpg" to reference it, and works in both Eclipse and JAR